# Netlogo How to make turtles avoid certain patch

Tags: netlogo

I am using netlogo to simulate the migration of some fish, if pcolor==98, then they can swim in any direction, but they can't move to patches with pcolor==0, how do I set it?
My code is below.

```
if pcolor = 98 [
      rt random 360
      fd 1
      set heading 0
    ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can search in the Models Library (`Strg` + `m`) for the "Look Ahead Example". It shows how to code walls or barriers.

Comment: It's not clear what the limitation is. Do you mean that they pick a direction,  and if the direction leads to a pcolor 0 patch they don't move? Or, do you mean, they should only pick a direction that leads to color 98? Must the angle be random, or can it be directly toward the center of the next patch? Is it OK if the fish passes over the corner of a color 0 patch on the way to the color 98 patch?